# importmap and module don't work in vanilla JavaScript with Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Why doesn't `importmap` work, and why do `export` and `import` not function at all in vanilla JavaScript files despite specifying `type='module'?` This was tested in three modern browsers. The scripts can only be connected using `<script src='...'>`
Previously, everything was working even though it was written using `importmap`. Could it be because that it was connected without `importmap` before? Please advise on how to solve this issue; I would like to use `export/import` and `importmap`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "@stomp/stompjs": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@stomp/stompjs@7.0.0/esm6/index.js",
          "sockjs-client": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sockjs-client@1.6.1/+esm",
          "popper": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "bootstrap": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "shoppingCart": "/shoppingCart.js",
          "messaging": "/messaging.js"
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script type="module">
        import "@stomp/stompjs";
        import "sockjs-client";
        import "popper";
        import "bootstrap";
        import "shoppingCart";
        import "messaging";
    </script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your importmap looks good but it seems like you are not using module import syntax correctly. Please review the [mdn module guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) and try this example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "@stomp/stompjs": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@stomp/stompjs@7.0.0/esm6/index.js",
          "sockjs-client": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sockjs-client@1.6.1/+esm",
          "@popperjs/core": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "bootstrap": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "shoppingCart": "./shoppingCart.js",
          "messaging": "./messaging.js"
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script type="module">
        import { Client } from '@stomp/stompjs';
        import * as sockjs from  "sockjs-client";
        import '@popperjs/core';
        import "bootstrap";
        import { shoppingCart } from './shoppingCart.js';
        import { messaging } from './messaging.js'

        const SockJS = sockjs.default;
        console.log({ Client, SockJS, Popper, bootstrap, shoppingCart, messaging });
    </script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and taking your time on this! It works fine now.

Comment: YW. I'm glad it does.